# How to use the map function correcly, to apply a function to every element in a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, tree, map-function

I have a quation about the following method.

So my goal is to output every Data Node (or leaf) of this MultTree:

```
data MultTree a = Indexnode a a [MultTree a] | Datanode a deriving Show
```

What I have so far is this:

```
dataList :: MultTree a -> [a]
dataList (Indexnode _ _ []) = []
dataList (Datanode a) = [a]
dataList (Indexnode _ _ (x:y:z)) = (dataList x) ++ (dataList y)
```

This will output the first two elements. And I understand why. But I'd like to output every element. So I suppose, I have to apply the function *dataList* to every element of the childList, kind of like this:

```
dataList (Indexnode _ _ childList) = (dataList childlist)
```

Of course this particular example will not work. I also know that, in order to apply a fuction to every element of a list, I should use the *map* function. And I have. But apparantly I'm too dumb to actually apply it. Whatever it is, it doesn't work.

I'd be more than grateful, if someone could show me, how to use the *map* function correctly in this case, or if I'm totally wrong and *map* is not the right way to go, what else I can do.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: `Whatever it is, it doesn't work.`. Could you show what you've tried, exactly, so we can see what the problem is? One pointer I can give is that `dataList (Indexnode _ _ childList) = map dataList childList` will fail to compile, because the output will be a `[[a]]` instead of `[a]`. So you probably want to apply `concat` to that (or simplify the code by using `concatMap` instead of `map`.

Comment: Yes basically what I tried was this: `dataList (Indexnode _ _ childList) = map(datalist childList)`. Sometimes with the paranthesis, without, all combinations I could think of.

Comment: Oh my god, concatMap worked! Thank you so much!